# VBA scripting on excel to delete rows with specific strings

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently in the process of writing a macro on excel that deletes an entire row which includes a specific string. I am doing some data analytics and would like to filter out a spreadsheet with not needed information.

An arbitrary example:

[image]

How would I go about making a script that deletes rows that include the color red, blue, and yellow?

Comment: show us what you have written so far

Comment: If you don't know where to start, look at literally any of the "related" posts on this page. NB: you'll need to do this in reverse order. Start with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023377/remove-duplicate-rows-excel-vba?rq=1) and see if that points you in the right direction.

Comment: To piggyback off David - There is at least one post a day made asking for code to delete rows containing certain text. You can almost certainly find a working example around here somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code.

```
Sub test()
    Dim rngDB As Range, rngU As Range, rngF As Range
    Dim vColor, i As Integer, Adr As String

    Set rngDB = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    vColor = Array("red", "yellow", "blue")

    For i = 0 To UBound(vColor)
        With rngDB
            Set rngF = .Find(vColor(i), LookIn:=xlValues, Lookat:=xlWhole)
            If rngF Is Nothing Then
            Else
                Adr = rngF.Address
                Do
                    If rngU Is Nothing Then
                        Set rngU = rngF
                    Else
                        Set rngU = Union(rngU, rngF)
                    End If
                    Set rngF = .FindNext(rngF)
                Loop Until Adr = rngF.Address Or rngF Is Nothing
            End If
        End With
    Next i
    If rngU Is Nothing Then
    Else
        rngU.EntireRow.Delete
    End If
End Sub
```